# Why does conversion of int -> hex/oct/bin print as plain decimal value in output?

Tags: c++, stringstream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     // <variables>
     int t = 0b11011101;

     stringstream aa;

     int n;
     string hexed;
     int hexedNot;
     // </variables>

     aa << t;
     aa >> n;
     cout << n << endl; // output 221
     aa.clear();

     aa << hex << n;
     aa >> hexed;
     aa.clear();

     aa << hex << n;
     aa >> hexedNot;
     cout << hexed << endl; // output dd

     cout << hexedNot; // output 221

     return 2137;
}
```

I want to convert int decimals to hex/oct/bin ints with stringstream, but I don't know how to approach it properly. If I try to convert it to a string containing hex, it's fine, but when I try to do the same with an integer, it just doesn't work. Any ideas? I can't use c++11 and I want to do it in a really slim and easy way.

I know that I can use `cout << hex << something;`, but that would just change my output and it wouldn't write the hexified value into my variable.

Comment: Besides your conversions are a bit of useless, to get the hexadecimal representation of `221` printed on the terminal, just write `cout << hex << hexedNot; // output 221`

Comment: This doesn't change my variable, just the output. I want to have a formatted variable. Thanks for answering!

Comment: There's no thing like a _"formatted variable"_ in c++.

Comment: Well, I'm self-taught and I don't know how it should be called, but I want to have a variable int X = 0xDD or int X = 0b11011101 if that's possible. If not, I'll continue to use the cout << hex << sth; like I always have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::string hexed;` was read from the `std::stream`, where you read after injecting a hexadecimal representation of `n` to the stream:

```
 aa << hex << n;
```

The next operation

```
 aa >> hexed;
```

reads from the stream to the `std::string` variable. Hence

```
cout << hexed << endl; // output dd
```

---

You seem to have a big misconception:

> I know that I can use `cout << hex << something;`, but that would just change my output **and it wouldn't write the** ***hexified*** **value into my variable**.

There's no thing like *"hexified value"* in c++ or any other programming languages. There are just (integer) **values**.

Integers are integers, their representation in input/output is a different kettle of fish:

It's not bound directly to their variable type or what representation they were initialized from, but what you tell the `std::istream`/`std::ostream` to do.

To get the hexadecimal representation of `221` printed on the terminal, just write

```
cout << hex << hexedNot;
```

---

As for your comment:

> but I want to have a variable int X = 0xDD or int X = 0b11011101 if that's possible. If not, I'll continue to use the cout << hex << sth; like I always have.

Of course these are possible. Rather than insisting of their textual representation you should try

```
int hexValue = 0xDD;
int binValue = 0b11011101;
if(hexValue == binValue) {
    cout << "Wow, 0xDD and 0b11011101 represent the same int value!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: The true question is, how can I get a decimal value via integer and store it in an int, but in hex format like you did? That's what I wanted to achieve, but, going further and further into your answer, I've noticed that a decimal integer with proper cout manipulation could do just fine in this case. I'm just wondering if this problem I've come across is possible to solve. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @noczesc I'm not really sure what that problem is you have. Anyways I'd recommend to use `std::istringstream` and `std::ostringstream` separately, because behavior of `std::stringstream` sometimes comes up weird using repeated write and read operations.

Comment: I'll try to use a simplified example. We have three integer variables - x = (hex), y = (bin), z = (oct); I want to create a situation in which, when I do cout << x;, the program prints a hex value of x without any cout manipulation like cout << hex << x; and the same goes for y and z. I think that it's not possible, because of the nature of integers in C++. Anyway, you've been a huge help for me, I think that I understand the issue now.

Comment: @noczesc _"... without any cout manipulation ..."_ As mentioned, you cannot. These are all just `int` values, and how they are represented is a property of the stream.

Comment: I get it now, I'll use your way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse [presentation and content](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content).

Integers (as all other values) are stored as binary in computer memory ("content"). Whether `cout` prints that in binary, hexadecimal, or decimal, is just a formatting thing ("representation"). `0b11011101`, `0xdd`, and `221` are all just different *representations* of the *same* number.

C++ or any other language I know, doesn't store formatting information with integer variables. But you can always create your own type to do that:

```
// The type of std::dec, std::hex, std::oct:
using FormattingType = std::ios_base&(&)(std::ios_base&);

class IntWithRepresentation {
public:
  IntWithRepresentation(int value, FormattingType formatting)
  : value(value), formatting(formatting) {}

  int value;
  FormattingType formatting;
};

// Overload std::cout <<
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output_stream, IntWithRepresentation const& i) {
  output_stream << i.formatting << i.value;
  return output_stream;
}

int main() {
  IntWithRepresentation dec = {221, std::dec};
  IntWithRepresentation hex = {0xdd, std::hex};
  IntWithRepresentation oct = {221, std::oct};

  std::cout << dec << std::endl;
  std::cout << hex << std::endl;
  std::cout << oct << std::endl;
}
```